# R String Processing -

Tags: r

I have below data frame with two input string (input1 & input2 column) and need help to convert the output string (as described in the output column). I am looking for solution using base R (preferably regular expression)

```
df <- data.frame(input1=c("0000.00", "0000.00", "0000.00"),
                 input2 = c("23.3", "23", "2323.23"), 
                 output = c("0023.30", "0023.00", "2323.23"))
```

Comment: Hi,Please try something like this.hope this will help.```df$output <- paste0(df$input1,"",df$input2)``` you have split the data after this to get your answer.

Comment: If you want to format numbers, then you can use functions like `format` or `formatC`. There may be a better way if you try and approach it like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, it uses `formatC` to get the right output width and decimal places. It determines the numbers of digits before and after the decimal point with `strsplit/sapply/nchar`.

```
fun <- function(X){
  sp <- strsplit(as.character(X[[1]]), "\\.")
  m <- max(nchar(sapply(sp, '[[', 1)))
  n <- max(nchar(sapply(sp, '[[', 2)))

  formatC(as.numeric(as.character(X[[2]])),
          digits = n, width = m + n + 1, 
          format = "f", flag = "0")
}

fun(df)
#[1] "0023.30" "0023.00" "2323.23"
```